# Error: Call to undefined function recaptcha_check_answer() in CakePHP 2.5.1 (PHP 5.3.28)

Tags: cakephp, recaptcha

I am trying to add google's reCAPTCHA in my CakePHP application's login and registration pages. But it showing following error:

Fatal Error
Error: Call to undefined function recaptcha_check_answer()
File: C:...\app\Controller\UsersController.php

in the UsersController , i have following line which is indicated in the error message.

```
$recaptchaResp = recaptcha_check_answer(Configure::read("Recaptcha.privateKey"),
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],

                            $this->params['form']["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $this->params['form']["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Could anyone tell me please what 's wrong in this code ? is it missing any file like recaptchalib ? if so, where can i get this library for CakePHP 2.5.1 ?

Comment: Just read the error message and you know what is wrong? If you read it but didn't understood it just Google it or check the php manual.

Comment: You answered your own question: "Error: Call to undefined function recaptcha_check_answer()".

Comment: i already googled this problem, but could not find any solution. there are some suggestion about how to add reCAPTCHA in PHP application. but it is not precise about how to integrate it in application which is developed in CakePHP 2.5.1 (PHP 5.3.28). it seems there are different methods to add this plugin.

Comment: @burzum, is php manual applicable for CakePHP 2.5.1 ?

Comment: You know that CakePHP is written in normal php? So yes, it is applicable. Your problem has *nothing* at all to do with Cake or Recaptcha, it is a *very* obviously parser error!

Comment: @Tom you haven't included where that function is declared. i.e. according to [the docs for that](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php) you're missing `require_once('recaptchalib.php');` or equivalent; writing an app with CakePHP doesn't fundamentally change that your app is written in ... PHP.

Comment: @AD7six , where to include this line ? it seems there are different approach for adding this plugin for PHP and CakePHP applications. is your mentioned link applicable for CakePHP app ?

Comment: @AD7six, ok , can you tell me where to define require_once('recaptchalib.php'); ?

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for google reCaptcha in cakephp. You can download it from [Here](https://github.com/bhanwarpsrathore/reCaptcha)

To use the recaptcha plugin its required to include the following two lines in your `/app/Config/bootstrap.php` file.

```
Configure::write('Recaptcha.publicKey', 'public-api-key');
Configure::write('Recaptcha.privateKey', 'private-api-key');
```

Controllers that will be using recaptcha require the Recaptcha Component to be included. Through inclusion of the component, the helper is automatically made available to your views.

```
public $components = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
```

In the view simply call the helpers display() method to render the recaptcha input:

```
echo $this->Recaptcha->display();
```

To check the result simply do something like this in your controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Recaptcha->verify()) {
        // verified
    } else {
        // display the error
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually answered the question, only proposed a different solution.

Comment: @AIPD TECH , i downloaded the plugin from the site you mentioned, but there is no recaptchalib file. how does it work without this recaptchalib ?

Comment: @Tom Its there in vendor, Have you tried the plugin?

Comment: @AIPD TECH , in vendor, there is a file ReCaptcha.php. is it the recaptchalib file to be included in app/Vendor folder in CakePHP ?

Comment: @Tom All you have to do is include the plugin, place keys in `bootstrap.php`, load the component, and display using `$this->Recaptcha->display()`, and verify using `$this->Recaptcha->verify()` and you are done.

Comment: Have a look at the one fron CakeDc

Comment: @tersmitten Yes it is modified version on cakeDC recaptcha. It shows `I'm not a robot' recaptcha while CakeDC one shows picture captcha

Comment: @AIPD TECH I understand